# Can't retrieve $_POST value from URL

Tags: php, url, post

I am working on a task and have set up my code as follows:
On `index.php` I include a file, which serves as a view with the code:

```
include 'Controller/CallArticleData.php';

$i = count($display) - 1;

while ($i >= 0) {
    echo "<a href='index.php?editID=" . $display[$i]['ID'] . "'>" . $display[$i]['title'] . "</a><br/>";
    $i--;
}
```

Basically, I call the controller, which calls the relevant model and then I use the data to setup the URL - I want it to set `$_POST['editID']` whenever a user clicks on the respective link.

However, the variable still remains unset upon hitting the link, even though the URL changes to `index.php?editID=12345`. I performed this check both in index.php and in the respective view.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$_GET` to access querystring parameters:

```
$_POST['editID']
```

should be

```
$_GET['editID']
```

Comment: Oh God, I can't believe I'm such a fool :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`$_GET` variables come from the query string. `$_POST` variables come from submitting forms with action="post").

Try changing

```
$_POST['editID']
```

to

```
$_GET['editID']
```

Comment: Quite a foolish mistake of mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `$_GET['editID']` instead of `$_POST['editID']`

Info about:

```
GET - Requests data from a specified resource
POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource
```

The GET Method: $_GET

Note that query strings (name/value pairs) is sent in the URL of a GET request.

filename?name1=value1&name2=value2

The POST Method: $_POST

Note that query strings (name/value pairs) is sent in the HTTP message body of a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use get or request instead of post

$_GET['editID'];
or
$_REQUEST['editID'];